# ConcurrentModificationException in java even without iteration

Tags: java

Can anyone help me out with this code? It throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` . I do know that while iterating a collection and simultaneously adding or removing elements from it, we get a `ConcurrentModificationException` . But I am not iterating in the first place.

```
import java.util.*;
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
ListIterator<String> itr = arr.listIterator();
arr.add("Hello");
arr.add("hi");
System.out.println(itr.next());
}
}
```

Comment: And, if I replace `ArrayList` with `CopyOnWriteArrayList` it shows a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Why do you believe that creating an `Iterator` and calling its `next()` method is not iterating?  The code you show could be considered a canonical example of _"How to cause `ConcurrentModificationException ` to be thrown"_

Comment: What do you think "iterating" means? Calling `itr.next()` *is* iterating. The iteration started when you called `listIterator()`, and continued when you called `next()`, and the list was modified in-between (aka "concurrently"), so you get the error. What's not to understand about that?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `itr.next()`, you *are* iterating the list (just not completely). A foreach loop in Java is really just syntactic sugar for:

```
Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    T curr = it.next();
}
```

When modifying the collection, all existing iterators are invalidated, whether you've used them or not yet. You must obtain a new iterator after modifying the list.

Comment: Well, technically `for (T curr : list) { ... }` is syntactic sugar for `for (Iterator<T> it$ = list.iterator(); it$.hasNext(); ) { T curr = it$.next(); ... }`, where iterator variable in internal and scoped to loop block. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The iterators of ArrayList are failfast means if you are trying to iterate and add/remove elements at the same time, the Iterator or ListIterator will throw ConcurrentModificationException.

```
itr.next() // this is iterating(going over the ArrayList)

arr.add("Hello");//This statement is adding to the ArrayList during iteration
arr.add("hi");//Again this statement is adding to ArrayList during iteration
```

This causes the ConcurrentModificationException.

If you want to iterate as well as modify(add/remove) the collection simulateously use CopyOnWriteArrayList,ConcurrentHashMap. The iterators of CopyOnWriteArrayList,ConcurrentHashMap are failsafe.